# error with the " .... WHERE A = 'B' request

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL server 2008. I have a database (table name :Data) where one column's name is title and another one is date.

One of the entry in the first column is :

```
WOLVERINE LE COMBAT DE L'IMMORTEL
```

However here what is not working :

```
select date from Data where title = 'WOLVERINE LE COMBAT DE L''IMMORTEL'
select date , title from Data where title LIKE '%WOLVERINE LE COMBAT DE L''IMMORTEL%'
select date , title from Data where title LIKE '%WOLVERINE LE%'
```

Here what is working :

```
 select date , title from Data where title LIKE '%WOLVERINE%'
 select date , title from Data where title LIKE '%LE COMBAT DE L''IMMORTEL%'


 select date , title from Data where title LIKE '%WOLVERINE  LE%'
```

Yes, it works for 'WOLVERINE  LE' when there is two spaces, even though I am pretty sure there is only one space in the database ( that is the case when I do a request). 
Does someone know how come there is this error ?

EDIT : Well sorry it seems like there was really two spaces between them, when I tried to display it in my aspx page, the two spaces are automatically replaced with one space, that is why I could not see it.

Comment: Your queries are working just fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/285e7/3. You have extra spaces in your data

Comment: Separate issue, but much better to use __prepared statements__ and bind parameters. Relying on quoting is unreliable & leaves your database open to hackers.

Comment: You are right, I will use  prepared statements and bind parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any confusion about the no. of spaces then just remove all the **`white space`** form both the sides

```
select date 
from Data 
where REPLACE(title,' ','') = REPLACE('WOLVERINE LE COMBAT DE L''IMMORTEL',' ','')
```

Comment: I just tried but it doesn't return anything, however `LTRIM(RTRIM(title)) = LTRIM(RTRIM('WOLVERINE  LE COMBAT DE L''IMMORTEL'))` (two spaces) works.

Comment: TRIM functions removes spaces from the start and end of the string only. Op wants to remove multiple spaces within a string.

Comment: @Exia0890 Can yo please check my updated answer/

Comment: Thanks :) , I did not know you could replace characters from the entry directly .